# rxgraph refresh

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to refresh the graph being shown on rxgraph? Because sometimes, it seems like it is getting stuck or fails to update itself and refresh the updated ROS node network.

I have 2 nodes running. I stopped one node and restarted it again. rxgraph still seems to show the 'graph node' depicting the earlier ROS node. When I hover the mouse over it, it simply says "Communication with node failed"..

But ofcourse both the ROS nodes are working fine. rxgraph simply can't seem to pick up the changes. Are there any refresh shortcuts that I might have missed?

Thanks and regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28064/rxgraph-refresh/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*Beware*: if you started the nodes with `roslaunch` and there was no `roscore` already running, then restarting causes the old master to shut down and a new one to start up.

If that happens, you'll need to restart `rxgraph` (and everything else).

If that *is* your problem, starting `roscore` first in a separate window is a good work-around.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-21**:
The problem is not that Im starting the nodes with roslaunch. I started roscore independently. Then started the nodes and finally rxgraph. Now in between, I start and stop different nodes expecting rxgraph to update itself. But it does not. I don't start and stop roscore itself..